# How to remove empty parts of the plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

I have a question regarding R plot.
The problem is that I have my graph in the centre of the plot and would like to remove unnecessary empty space around it.
Setting limits to the axes did not help.

my R code is below:

```
visualize_circle_arrows <- function(x) {
  colors<- unlist(lapply(x$MeanOffsetLength,get_grey_color, max(x$MeanOffsetLength), min(x$MeanOffsetLength)), recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
  library(graphics)
  plot(x$IconCenterX, -x$IconCenterY, xlim=c(0, 1080), ylim=c(-1920, 0), asp=1, cex = .05, col = "blue", main="Offset vector for Thumb in warm",
       xlab="X coordinates of the screen, px", ylab="Y coordinates of the screen, px")
  radius <- rep(135,times=nrow(x)) 

  symbols(x$IconCenterX, -x$IconCenterY, circles=radius, add=TRUE, inches=FALSE, bg=colors)

  arrows(x$IconCenterX, -x$IconCenterY, x1 = x$MeanTouchX, y1 = -x$MeanTouchY, length = 0.04, angle = 25,
         code = 2, col = "black", lty = par("lty"),
         lwd = 2)
}

get_grey_color <- function(x,max=135, min=0) {
  value <- ((x+10-min)/(max+10-min))
  rgb(value, value, value)
}
visualize_circle_arrows(warm_thumb)
```

and the result of it is this graph below
[my graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VetyI.png)

Any help will be very much appreciated!
Thanks a lot!

p.s. snapshot of warmthumb object is here
[warmthumb object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCSeX.png)

Comment: what clas is `warm_thumb` ? A reproducible example would be helpful.

Comment: my bad, forgot to put it there, i will attach a snapshot to my question

Comment: please use`dput()` to create an example dataset we can load. I think the problem here lies in the class of the object, which can't be analysed from your screenshot